# Intersection observer cleans React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I'm using Intersection Observer to see if div element is in viewport, which actually is bottom of page. In useEffect hook I'm fetching blogs from Firestore and saving to state and after I scroll to bottom second fetching function runs, which fetches another blogs. I'm setting blogs state with previous blogs and new blogs, but somehow previous blogs is empty array.
It only outputs new blogs and old is gone.

getBlogs is getting docs from Firestore and creating new array with fetched blogs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BlogListItem from './BlogListItem';
import db from '../firebase/firebase';
import BlogFilters from './BlogFilters';
import loader from '../images/loader.gif';
import RecentFeed from './RecentFeed';
import BlogsContext from '../context/blogs-context';

let startDoc = null;

const getBlogs = docs => {
    const blogs = [];
    docs.forEach(doc => {
        blogs.push({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
        });
    });
    startDoc = docs[docs.length - 1];
    return blogs;
};

const firstFetchBlogs = async () => {
    const data = await db.collection('blogs').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(5).get();
    return getBlogs(data.docs);
};

const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    const data = await db.collection('blogs').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').startAfter(startDoc).limit(5).get();
    return getBlogs(data.docs);
};

export const ReadBlogList = () => {
    const [ blogs, setBlogs ] = useState([]);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ smallLoading, setSmallLoading ] = useState(false);
    const [ noMore, setNoMore ] = useState(false);

    const scrollElement = React.useRef();

    const paginateBlogs = () => {
        setSmallLoading(true);
        fetchBlogs()
            .then(newBlogs => {
                setBlogs([ ...blogs, ...newBlogs ]);
                setSmallLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                setSmallLoading(false);
                setNoMore(true);
            });
    };
    const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        const ratio = entries[0].intersectionRatio;
        if (ratio > 0) {
            paginateBlogs();
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let didCancel = false;
        firstFetchBlogs().then(newBlogs => {
            if (!didCancel) {
                setBlogs(newBlogs);
                setLoading(false);
                io.observe(scrollElement.current);
            }
        });
        return () => {
            didCancel = true;
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container read-blog-list">
            <BlogFilters />

            {loading && <img src={loader} alt="Loader" />}

            {!loading && (
                <BlogsContext.Provider value={{ blogs }}>
                    <div className="read-blog-list__content">
                        {blogs.length > 0 ? (
                            <div className="read-blog-list__blogs">
                                {blogs.map(blog => <BlogListItem to="read" key={blog.id} {...blog} />)}
                                <div ref={scrollElement} />
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                            noMore && <p className="text-grey-darkest text-center text-xl">No more blogs</p>
                        )}

                        <RecentFeed />

                        {smallLoading && (
                            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                                <img className="w-12 h-12" src={loader} alt="Loader" />
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </BlogsContext.Provider>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    filters: state.filters,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReadBlogList);
```

Comment: I'm trying to walk through your code, and I noticed there's no error handling on your firstFetchBlogs function.  I think you should rewrite, with a try/catch, like this:  

const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    try {
             const data = await db.collection('blogs').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').startAfter(startDoc).limit(5).get();

              return getBlogs(data.docs);

          } catch (err) {

               console.log(err)
         }
};

.. to make sure you're not getting an error there.  (Just one thing I spotted, didn't make it through whole code yet).

Comment: Is there any news on this questions?) I just faced with the same issue